# Template function(s) which vary depending on class member function arguments

Tags: c++, sfinae, member-functions

There are two types of objects in the hierarchy, but they both have a static "find" method that I want to call. The second parameter is the name of the object, and the first is the container. Some of the classes have a find method that searches in the "database" (i.e., that's the first parameter), and some of the classes have a find method that searches in a subcontainer of that database, which is itself a class in this hierarchy.

I want to create a template function (well, or a SFINAE set thereof) that does the right thing, depending on the signature of the find method that it has. I'm trying to avoid my old lazy, satisficient strategy of basic default implementation and having to special case for the other cases even though they are the same alternate type of implementation.

Honestly, this SFINAE stuff kind of causes my head to explode. I've seen examples to handle "has-member" situation, but I don't think I've found an example of handling the branch between "has this member-sig" and "has other member-sig". So it's kind of a tri-state, I guess, though we won't necessarily run into the situation that a call is made with a class that simply doesn't have that member function.

```
class Db;
class Obj { /*...*/ Db* getDb(); /*...*/ };
class Guts : public Obj { /*...*/ };
class Db : public Obj { /*...*/ Guts* getGuts(); /*...*/ };
class ChildA : public Obj { static ChildA* find(Db* db, const std::string& name); /*...*/ };
class ChildB : public Obj { static ChildB* find(Guts* dbg, const std::string& name); /*...*/ };

template <typename T>
bool findByName(Db* db, const std::string& name, T*& ret);
```

Any tips or suggestions? Any references to topics that already cover this? C++11 version preferable.

I think what I'm not seeing, and sorry for the need of hand-holding here, is how to express the findByName implementations using the SFINAE-related signatures. I see similar questions, but my tiny brain is not able to make the connection there. ;p

Comment: Can you show the (non template) expected result for your case? I don't see your tri-state...

Comment: Perhaps I should have asked for some clarification before answering. `findByName`'s first argument is `Db*`. Is that deliberate or should it be a template parameter type? Is `T` one of the `Child` types? I'd like to see the same as @Jarod42 asked for or at least some pseudo code with instances of your defined classes used with `findByName`.

Comment: JBaudhuin: Did you abandon this question? I found the question interesting and would like to try to provide a better answer if my current isn't enough. Can you provide more info?

Answer (score 0):

If you make the `find` methods `public` you could test the signatures like this:

```
#include <utility>

template<class T, class... Signature>
struct has_find_signature {
    template<class> struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

    // fake functions, only to be used in SFINAE context
    template<class U>
    static auto test_find(int) -> // returns a sfinae_true<> if SFINAE succeeds
        sfinae_true<
            // std::declval<U>().  could be just  U::  since it's a static method 
            decltype( std::declval<U>().find( std::declval<Signature>()... ) )
        >;

    template<class U>
    static auto test_find(long) -> std::false_type;

    // decltype of a fake call to test_find() with an int to try the true_type (int)
    // version first and only fall back on the false_type (long) version if SFINAE fails.
    static constexpr bool value = decltype(test_find<T>(0))::value;
};

// Helper variable template (C++14 required):
template<class T, class... Signature>
constexpr bool has_find_signature_v = has_find_signature<T, Signature...>::value;
```

You could then use it in other templates or in `if constexpr` situations.

This would print `1001` in your case:

```
std::cout
    << has_find_signature_v<ChildA, Db*, std::string>        // C++14
    << has_find_signature_v<ChildA, Guts*, std::string>      // C++14

    << has_find_signature<ChildB, Db*, std::string>::value   // C++11
    << has_find_signature<ChildB, Guts*, std::string>::value // C++11
;
```